# Twitter Error Could not post Tweet

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

What could be this Error?

```
Could not post Tweet. Error: 403 Reason: Status is a duplicate.
```

actually this is a edited message . 
i get error code as `403` and Reason as `Status is a duplicate`.

Comment: You can post (repost) a tweet with the same status of a previous one only if  it has one or more media file (ex: image) or if the status contains a link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Twitter checks messages if they are duplicates of the previous and does not accept them a second time.

So for testing you need to generate new messages (=content) each time.

This is documented somewhere at Twitter, but you can also read about on [other sites](http://techcrunch.com/2009/10/14/cleaning-up-the-stream-twitter-kills-duplicate-tweets/).

Answer (score 4):

The status is a duplicate, probably running your script twice without changing the status message.

Delete your last status update via Twitter web and run the script again. Or include date('r') or md5(mt_rand()) with your status message to generate a different one each time the script is run.

Answer (score 0):

I also had encountered the same error. what the twitter site says is that they check the messages tweeted and discard (refuse) them if they are same. [Discussion](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/574) here says to use different texts each time you make a tweet. Else use a different account for tweeting.

Answer (score 0):

```
  import time, os, random, hashlib, datetime

  gettime = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
  random_data = os.urandom(128)
  hash = hashlib.md5(gettime).hexdigest()[:8]
  twitterpost = "foo bar %s" % hash
  api.update_status(status=twitterpost)
```